# PHP Include - not showing errors in included piece of code

Tags: php, error-handling

1) I have index.php script.

2) Inside it I have include("index_aside.inc");

When I have parse error in index.php

> if ($qw = 2) {  (unexpected eof)

I see error on screen.

When I put this line to **index_aside.inc** I get no error. Nothing from index_aside.inc shows in the browser.

How can I enable showing errors inside included files?

Thanks Pavel

Comment: have tried `error_reporting(E_ALL);` or `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` ?

Comment: in init.php i have
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ini_set('html_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT && ~ E_NOTICE);
 set_error_handler("golemErrorHandler", E_ALL | E_STRICT);
this file i include in index.php

Comment: Solved: error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT && ~ E_NOTICE); did the mess. I changed to error_reporting(E_ALL); and errors show even in included files, which didn't showed only in index.php - which is wierd.

Comment: Unexpected eof usually is because of a syntax error in your code structure. In this case I guess in within your included file. Try running this file standalone and see for errors or use a IDE with syntax checker.